How do I solve this differential equation (1-x^2)y'=x^2-xy-1 in SymPy as expected?
I want to solve (1-x^2)y'=x^2-xy-1 with Sympy, but I cannot solve it as expected.
I expect to get the following solution.
-1<x<1:y(x)=-sqrt(1-x**2)*asin(x)+C1*sqrt(1-x**2)
x<-1,x>1:y(x)=-sqrt(x**2-1)*log(abs(x+sqrt(x**2-1)))+C1*sqrt(x**2-1)
x=0:y=0

But as far as I have tried, I could not get this answer.
How can I do this?
In Sympy I ran the following code and got the following output.
x, C1= symbols("x, C1")
y = symbols('y',cls=Function)
eq=Eq((1-x**2)*Derivative(y(x),x),x**2-x*y(x)-1)
sols = dsolve(eq,y(x),hint='all')
exp_fin=False
for k,v in sols.items():
  if k=="best":
    exp_fin=True
    continue
  print("--------------------------------")
  print(k)
  display(v if exp_fin else v.doit())




In my research I found that (https://www.symbolab.com/) can find the expected solution for -1<x<1. Why can't Sympy do this? This site is not very flexible and still needs a Sympy solution.

Well, to be fair, the forms of the solution marked “almost linear integral”, first linear integral” and  “Bernoulli” are correct, albeit they will need some complex-number manipulation where -1<x<1.

So y(x)=(C1-log(x+sqrt(x2-1)))*sqrt(x2-1) can be transformed as y(x)=-sqrt(1-x2)asin(x)+C1sqrt(1-x2)?

Yes, they can be transformed between each other - but you have to do so through complex numbers. I'll try and write you out the derivation.

OK, here goes. Any errors in the maths below ... let me know (gently!)
The solution given by SymPy is of the form

Obviously, this looks most appropriate for abs(x)>1 because the quantity to be square-rooted is positive there. However, if you accept that functions of complex variables are OK – as NumPy does – then it will also apply for abs(x)<1.
You would like it to be shown (because it is more useful for -1<x<1) that it can also be written

(where I prefer this notation for arcsin(x) when I’m deriving things). The derivation below is very similar to what is done as a standard school exercise for arcsinh(x), where sinh(x) is the corresponding hyperbolic function.
Let

Then

Multiplying by 2i.exp(iy) and rearranging gives

and hence, by quadratic formula,

Hence,

(WLOG we can choose the positive square root – the alternative could be rearranged to combine with the initial constant). Hence,

Then, back to the SymPy solution, writing the square-root bit the opposite way round to extract a factor of -i (obviously I could also extract +i, but that’s the nature of square roots):

where I have combined the constant parts into a new constant of integration, C2. So, the SymPy solution could be transformed to one of the form

which is your desired alternative.
So, could you get your intended asin(x) form directly from Sympy?
Well, sort of. You have to rearrange your equation (code below) to force the "direction" of the square root. (This is how I manually solved your equation, in fact, using an integrating factor). Running the code below, ONE of the proposed solutions (the one marked "1st exact") gives the asin(x) form. However, most of the other solutions still use the log form (which is a bit easier with complex numbers).
from sympy import *

x, C1= symbols("x, C1",complex=False)
y = symbols('y',cls=Function)
#eq=Eq((1-x**2)*Derivative(y(x),x),x**2-x*y(x)-1)
eq=Eq(diff(y(x)/sqrt(1-x**2),x),-1/sqrt(1-x**2))
sols = dsolve(eq,y(x),hint='all',simplify=True)
exp_fin=False
for k,v in sols.items():
  if k=="best":
    exp_fin=True
    continue
  print("--------------------------------")
  print(k)
# display(v if exp_fin else v.doit())
  print(v)

Are there other ways of writing the solution?
Yes, plenty! Because of the periodicity of sin(x) and the simple phase difference of pi/2 between sin(x) and cos(x) any of the following would work just as well - any differences being absorbed into the constant:
(C1-asin(x))sqrt(1-x**2)
(C2+asin(x))sqrt(1-x**2)
(C3-acos(x))sqrt(1-x**2)
(C4+acos(x))sqrt(1-x**2)

So there is absolutely no reason to prefer one involving asin(x) from those involving -asin(x) or acos(x). In fact, the absence of this choice makes the log form quite attractive. For the record, log(x+sqrt(x**2-1)) can also be written acosh(x).

This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much!
I have an additional question. Which notation would be preferable as an indication of the solution?

It really depends what domain you are interested in. If you are only interested in x>1 then the log function would be better, since you could stay entirely in real variables. Similarly if your domain is guaranteed abs(x)<1 then asin() would be more natural. However, if you have to cover the whole range of x with a single function then I think NumPy's preference for the log function is the wise one. It's worth taking away from this thread the fact that there are multiple ways of writing a "solution" and that NumPy works very naturally with complex numbers.
